# how to interpret the ambiguity of this little text?

Tags: vocabulary, american-english, interpretation, learning

based on this short headline:

> For These Veterans, ‘Free’ Health Care Is a 5-Hour Flight Away
>
> Citizens of three Pacific Island nations, eligible to serve in the U.S. military, find it hard to make use of the health benefits they have earned.

who faces difficulty to get the free health care, Veterans or the Citizens eligible to serve in the U.S. military, as to my view they are opposite.

the Headline starts mentioning the veterans and in the middle switch to Citizens eligible to serve in the U.S. military, as someone learning english this can be bit confusing

Comment: A source would be helpful, but even like this it seems quite obvious some copy/paste mistake or something of the sort was made. And please format your question properly: I don't really see where the quote ends and your question continues.

Comment: No contradiction. Citizens of three Pacific Island nations who have served in the US military ('these veterans') are eligible for free medical care.

Comment: @Michael Harvey, the headline states the Citizens of three Pacific Island are aligible to serve in U.S. military, not that they've served.

Comment: @evanildalidantown 1. It starts with 'these veterans'. A 'veteran' in US English is a person who **has** served in the military. 2. The text says _the health benefits they **have** earned._

Comment: @ Michael Harvey, I think my formating was really bad: "For These Veterans, ‘Free’ Health Care Is a 5-Hour Flight Away" that is the title and then follow the textt bellow: "Citizens of three Pacific Island nations, eligible to serve in the U.S. military, find it hard to make use of the health benefits they have earned." so that where I see contradiction as you stated a Veteran in U.S English  is a person who has served in the military. so the text goes on and states " Citizens of three Pacific Island nations, eligible to serve in the U.S. military" one thing is opposite to other, right?

Comment: @Michael Harvey, A Veteran is not someone eligible for o serving in the U.S. military, right?

Comment: In a dictionary, you will find: A veteran of something specified is a person who has past experience of that thing, for example 'a veteran of many years as a bookseller', and also, in the USA, in connection with the military, 'a veteran' (just that, with nothing specified) is a person who has served in the US military in the past, and is not in the military any more. The word is sometimes spelled with a capital V to make this meaning clear.

Comment: In the US, there is an organisation called the Veterans Administration (often just called 'the VA') which provides hospitals and medical care for current and former members of the military and, in some cases, their families.

Comment: @Michael Harvey, that's what I thought. That is why I think the headline is confusing to me. It starting talking about the Veterans and then goes on to Citizens eligible to serve in the U.S. military. who actually faces difficulty in getting free health care??? maybe it's both. but it is not clear to me :(

Comment: The article is saying 1. Citizens of three Pacific Island nations are eligible to serve in the US military. 2. Those of them who have served in the past are entitled to free healthcare.

Comment: The citizens have to do the military service first to get the free healthcare benefits. The article is clumsily written.

Comment: @ Michael Harvey,that is what I thought either. But the headline goes on and also state that these Citizens  eligible to serve, ", find it hard to make use of the health benefits they have earned" so I got totally lost

Comment: It just conveys the information that the citizens of the island can serve in the US military and later get health benefits. Native speakers or readers know what a 'veteran' is.

Comment: @Michael Harvey, you've provided some further background to me and I got it now. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The citizens and veterans are the same people. Being a citizen doesn't mean you've never been in the military. In fact, for many militaries, you must be a citizen of the country to be eligible to serve. The word "citizen" is sometimes used to mean "ordinary citizen", as in, someone who is not a soldier, but the most common meaning is just someone who belongs to a certain country.

This story is about three Pacific Island nations where the citizens are eligible to serve in the U.S. Military. After these citizens serve, and are veterans, they find it difficult to access the services they are entitled to.

Comment: ♦, thank you very much for contributing, but don't you think at all this phraing is confusing? I mean to get the gist of "After these citizens serve, and are veterans, they find it difficult to access the services they are entitled to." was not easy for me, it was perceived naturally

Comment: ♦, the citizens eligible to serve in the U.S. Military, find it difficult to access the services they have earned. but they are yet to be  entitled to those benefits after serving, in the future. They don't know if it will still be difficulty to access those

Comment: The reader must infer that the citizens and the veterans are the same thing, but it's not difficult to do. It's clear to me what the meaning is

Comment: ♦, saying the citizens are "eligible to serve" is not a match with Veterans, right? I think the closest I got to a full interpretaion was taking into account the fact  'VA' which provides hospitals and medical care for current and former members of the military as mentioned by Michael Harvey. Don't you think it is likely the real interpretation?